# php REGEX match every line after a certain line

Tags: php, regex, multiline, preg-match-all

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP REGEX preg_math_all every line after a particular line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545478/php-regex-preg-math-all-every-line-after-a-particular-line)

I want a pattern that will match every line after a particular line - the only constant that I can rely on is that if the header is there I know I want the follow lines.  It doesn't matter if I end up getting more lines than I want because I'll only take the first however many I need.

```
SURGICAL/MEDICAL HISTORY <--Header to indicate the beginning of my list
HISTORY 1 <--line1 to be matched
HISTORY 2 <--line2 to be matched
HISTORY 3 <--line3 to be matched
.
.
```

I'm not posting a real sample of the text because it shouldn't matter - the pattern must be flexible and for other particular reasons.  I just always have such an issue with lines in regex.  Here is what I have:

```
$ptn = "/SURGICAL\/MEDICAL HISTORY\s*(^(.+)$)+/m";
```

But that only matches the first line. Thanks!

EDIT: I need all of the matched lines in separated in an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SURGICAL/MEDICAL HISTORY
HISTORY 1
HISTORY 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => HISTORY 1
            [1] => HISTORY 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful : [Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

> **s (PCRE_DOTALL)**
>
> > If this modifier is set, a dot
> >     metacharacter in the pattern matches
> >     all characters, including newlines.
> >     Without it, newlines are excluded.
> >     This modifier is equivalent to Perl's
> >     /s modifier. A negative class such as
> >     [^a] always matches a newline
> >     character, independent of the setting
> >     of this modifier.

Your final regex should look like this (not tested) :

```
$ptn = "/SURGICAL\/MEDICAL HISTORY\s*$(.*)/ms";
```

Comment: problem with that is I need to match the lines separately, what that does it is just returns them all in one key.