# PHP REGEX preg_match_all every line after a particular line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Here is the sample string with my regex and code:

```
$str = "Supp Fees:
----------
Oral Glucose
Glucagon
OXYGEN";

$ptn = "/----------(?:\r\n(.+))+/m";
preg_match_all($ptn,$str,$matches);

echo"<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo"</pre>";
```

I'm trying to match every line after '----------' the pattern above only returns the first line (Oral Glucose).  I can repeat the '\r\n(.+)' part and return another line but there is no telling how many lines there will be.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this without regex:

```
$data = substr($str, strpos($str, '----------') + 10);
$matches = explode("\r\n", $data);
```

Comment: You mean solving a string problem without REGEX!>!>!>!?! lol, it's funny how I've been using REGEX so much lately I didn't even consider using php functions. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$str = "Supp Fees:
----------
Oral Glucose
Glucagon
OXYGEN";


$str = explode('----------', $str);
preg_match_all("/[^\r\n].*/", $str[1], $matches);

echo"<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo"</pre>";

?>
```

?